# Pivot table "Sum of Value" shows 0 and only count works

Tags: excel, sum, pivot-table, datasheet, excel-2021

I have a data set with no blank cells and the format of all cells are numbers. When I try to create a `pivot table` for it, it by default takes the count of value. When I try to change the value field settings to `Sum`, the values become 0.
Please help

Tried to create a pivot table to show `sum` of values but it only shows the count of cells.
When I changed the value field settings to sum, the cell values all become 0

Comment: I assume the values are actually numbers stored as text. You should convert them to actual numerics.

Comment: @JosWoolley How do I do that?

Comment: Many ways. Quickest is usually to select the entire field and then use `Data/Text to Columns`, clicking 'Finish' in the very first window it presents.

Comment: Please refers to:  [Convert numbers stored as text to numbers](https://support.microsoft.com/en-au/office/convert-numbers-stored-as-text-to-numbers-40105f2a-fe79-4477-a171-c5bad0f0a885?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-33461)